# To color tint the MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

Is there any "proper" way to color tint the `MapView` ?
I'm looking for a proper solution to this problem.

Not posting the code because it won't help to answer the question anyway.

Note : Taking `MapView` inside a `FrameLayout` and then coloring the `FrameLayout` kind of hack is not what I am looking for.

Comment: that means your `MapView` is not covering the complete screen size?

Comment: No, but even if it was, would it make any difference ?

Comment: If you are talking about Google Maps, AFAIK, you can't change the color of the Google Map screen..although you can change the color of marker easily

Comment: I do not think there is a proper way. However you can set up a colored view over the map that is transparent and passes clicks.